# "MongoError: Can't extract geo keys from object" with Type : Point

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to prepare my database field for geocoding with this:

```
MyCollection._ensureIndex({'data.address.located':'2dsphere'});
```

But then this error comes:

```
MongoError: Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:
{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ 32.4586858, -110.8571443 ] }
```

I can not see whats wrong with this field ? Any idea ?

When I take a look to [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) it shows up this:

```
The following example stores a GeoJSON Point:

{ loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 40, 5 ] } }
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The problem is that

```
[ 32.4586858, -110.8571443 ]
```

is not a valid coordinate. The order should be longitude followed by latitude whereas that coordinate appears to be the reverse (judging by the fact that the valid latitude range is -90 to 90 and -110.8571443 is outside of that).

I think you meant:

```
{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ -110.8571443, 32.4586858 ] }
```

or there was some other entry error.

Comment: Damn ... you're right. This is so stupid ... I had the same problem a few days ago and fixed it ... and now the same error. Thanks ...

Comment: its happens on the best families! even on mine!

Comment: Mistakes happen. MongoDB could have a clearer message that explained that the failure reason was the longitude value was not valid.

Comment: I "love" that everyone blames themselves for this when every other system I've seen puts `lat` first.

Comment: @AndrewHedges that's the GeoJSON standard though. `lon` first!

Comment: Generally Lat come first. Mongo should give proper error in simple words.

Answer (score 9):

As [mentioned by **@go-oleg**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150815/1548719) the problem is that range of coordinate are next:

- Longitude: *(+-) 180°*
- Latitude: *(+-) 90°*

and index expects **coordinates** to be **in that bounds**.

But if you are trying to apply index on **already imported data** and found out that **coordinates are swapped**, you'll probably want to swap it back rather than reimporting whole collection. For this purpose you can use next `mongoshell` script.

> Assuming that you already have well-formed `GeoJSON` of type `Point`.

```js
db.coll.find().forEach(function (e) {
    // assuming that `geoJson` is our field containing `coordinates`
    e.geoJson.coordinates = [ // Swapping Lat/Lon
        e.geoJson.coordinates[1], // Longitude goes first
        e.geoJson.coordinates[0] // Latitude goes last
    ];
    db.coll.save(e);
    // Some `print(e.name)` can go here just to understand the progress
});
```

Comment: I take it MongoDB won't accept cartesian coordinates, only lat/long pairs?

Comment: @Mike you will go ok with your coordinates as long as they are in lon/lat bounds. Otherwise index will force you to limit your coordinates which easily can be beyond those limits and you will end up in the same lon/lat pair anyway.

Comment: @PaulT.Rawkeen Not working for me. db.coll.save(e) is not updating the 'coll' collection. No error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while my longitude, latitude order was correct. My mistake was that I had written `coordiantes` instead of `coordinates` the mongo gave me this:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Can't extract geo keys: {data}  Point must be an array or object
```

so maybe you have the right ordering but you have problem in your key names.

Answer (score 1):

Even the problem was solved, I need to highlight this bug also may appear if you omit the type of GeoJSON object.

In my case, it was corrected adding the `type: 'Point'` to model's value.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but the issue was I had a `LineString` with two identical coordinates.

```
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "LineString",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
            143.345763, 
            -33.840952
        ], 
        [ 
            143.345763, 
            -33.840952
        ]
    ]
}
```

I had to make this into a `Point` for it to be valid

```
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        143.345763, 
        -33.840952
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first step is to insert some data that should be in first object format otherwise this errors comes in picture

```
schema :
location:{
            type: { type: String },
            coordinates:[mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
        },
```

then insert some data into db

```
db.userDetails.createIndex({location: "2dsphere"})
```

index only be created if location contains object

after that write query ,if u want to findout distance

```
db.userDetails.aggregate( [
 $geoNear: {
                  near: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [data.lat1,data.lon1]},
                  spherical: true,
                  "distanceMultiplier" : 0.001,
                  distanceField: "calcDistance",
                  $maxDistance: distance,

               }
] )
```

and one more thing data should be pass without quoated string

```
"lat":18.7323
"lon":73.1232
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the coordinates were strings instead of integers/floats.

So I changed

```
{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ "8.73167870769231", "49.3182756076923" ] } }
```

To

```
{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ 8.73167870769231, 49.3182756076923 ] } }
```

With:

```
const lat = Number(old_lat)
```