# MongoDB query in nested key value and compare inside value list

Tags: java, mongodb, filter, documentfilter

My database looks like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8351093cf24e144d8fef24"),
  "__type" : "TrafficIncident:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
  "point" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
        37.410883,
        -95.71027
    ]
  },
  ...
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8351093cf24e144d8fef25"),
  "__type" : "TrafficIncident:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v2",
  "point" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
        40.2346,
        -100.826167
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

If I have a coordinates pair as center location, say [38, -98], and I want to retrieve all records with in coordinate range [38 +- 2, -98 +- 2], how to write java code for the Document Filter?

So far what I have done is retrieving a specific location instead of inside a range.

```java
Document query = new Document("point.coordinates", Arrays.asList(40.2346, -100.826167));
javamongo.collection.find(query).limit(javamongo.numLimit).forEach(printBlock);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use MongoDB's [Geospatial Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/) system for this.

I'm assuming you're using [Mongo's official Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/). First you'll want to create a `2dsphere` index on the `point.coordinates` field. You can do this in Java with:

```
collection.createIndex(Indexes.geo2dsphere("point.coordinates"));
```

Then you can query for all documents within your location range with:

```
Point refPoint = new Point(new Position(38, -98));
collection.find(Filters.near("point.coordinates", refPoint, 2, 2)).forEach(printBlock);
```

[MongoDB's tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/geospatial-search/) on geospatial search with their Java driver is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, I chose `geoWithin` and it worked perfectly. Another problem came with this is that MongoDB by default uses [(longitude, latitude)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) as query, while the data stored in my database is [latitude, longitude]. And hence it had the error ["Can't extract geo keys"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150590/mongoerror-cant-extract-geo-keys-from-object-with-type-point). Is there anyway to fix the query instead of changing or pre-processing data in database.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so and it looks like they have no plans on changing that - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27548

Comment: Well, that is interesting to know btw. Thank you for the helps.