# Unable to find index for $geoNear query error with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following codes which try to create secondary indexes with mongoose. I have followed the mongoose official document to implement it ( [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html): Indexes section). However, when I send a GET request through Postman, an error, "unable to find index for $geoNear query", occurs. My understanding is that in my case, `location` is equivalent to a `$geoNear` object, so my code should be fine (I know it's not fine. That's why I have got an error). Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

app.js(get endpoint)

```
app.get('/api/stores', (req, res) => {
    const zipCode = req.query.zip_code;

    const googleMapsURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
    axios.get(googleMapsURL, {
        params: {
            address: zipCode,
            key : "KEY"
        }
        
    }).then((response) => {
        const data = response.data
        const coordinates = [
            data.results[0].geometry.location.lng,
            data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
        ]
        
        Store.find({
            location: {
                $near: {
                    $maxDistance: 3218,
                    $geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: coordinates
                    }
                }
            }
        }, (err, stores)=> {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                
                res.status(200).send(stores);
            }
        })
    }).catch((error)=> {
        console.log(error);
    })
})
```

store.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const storeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    storeName: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    address: {},
    openStatusText: String,
    addressLines: Array,
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            required: true
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: true
        }
    }
})


storeSchema.index({ location : "2dsphere"}, {sparse: true});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Store', storeSchema);
```

[image]

Comment: Does the index exist in the database?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new index in MongoDB, you may have to drop the table as to have the index apply properly. Try creating the index on a fresh table. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this error by first creating a new database and collection(I was using the default database named `<dbname>`). When I sent a POST request with the data I would like to store in MongoDB, MongoError: Can't extract geo keys appeared. I fixed this error by following this thread([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150590/mongoerror-cant-extract-geo-keys-from-object-with-type-point)). After these steps, my GET request worked and indexes were successfully created.